# Monstera stopped growing

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, monstera

I have a beautiful Monstera, but it stopped growing.  The most recent leaf has never fully expanded, and has been in the state shown in the picture now for 4 months.
I've also stopped watering now, since it doesn't seem to be absorbing any water from the soil anymore.  I'm very worried that the plant might be dying.  Any suggestions what I could try to save it highly appreciated.

[image: Monstera leaf]
[image: Monstera]
[image: Monstera2]
[image: Monstera leaf 2]

Comment: couple of questions - is it winter where you are and how long has the plant been in that pot?

Comment: Hi @Bamboo, I'm in southern California so it's technically winter, but temperatures are rarely below 50Fº/10Cº.  I've also been keeping the plant indoors and it's been doing fine for the past 3 years.  About 1 year ago I moved it from a fairly small to the current bigger pot you see in the picture.

Comment: One more question - does the pot have drainage holes, or is it planted in a pot with drainage holes standing inside the outer pot? I can't see an internal pot...

Comment: The pot has one drainage hole, which drains into the attached saucer ... but we rarely water that much that a lot of water comes out.

Answer (score 1):

The plant might have hit its growth limit for that pot size. Consider repotting again using a larger pot and see if it resumes growth.

If you think it's a bit early for another repotting consider waiting for springtime, and see if the temperature increase will stimulate plant growth.

[The Spruce](https://www.thespruce.com/how-to-grow-monstera-deliciosa-5072671) recommends placing the Monstera under direct sunlight at least once a year:

> [...] set indoor plants outside at least once a year in direct sunlight to encourage lush growth.

Refer to the article for more juicy tips.

Good luck!